# XSLT Ignore namespace

Tags: xslt, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to get accustomed to XSLT, and I understand the reason for namespaces, but I'm simply trying to convert local XML files to be consumed by a local application.

I'm trying to convert the file found here: http://uscodebeta.house.gov/download/releasepoints/us/pl/113/31/xml_usc01@113-31.zip

using this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" name="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="//title">
        <xsl:for-each select="section">
            <xsl:variable name="href"><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::title/num/@value" />-<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::chapter/num/@value" />-<xsl:value-of select="num/@value" />.xml</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:result-document href="$href">
                <xsl:element name="structure">
                    <xsl:element name="unit">
                        <xsl:attribute name="label">title</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="identifier">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::title/num/@value" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="order_by">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::title/num/@value" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="level">1</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::title/num" /> <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::title/heading"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

into the XML example found here:
https://github.com/statedecoded/statedecoded/wiki/XML-Format-for-Parser

This is the conversion for just the first element, but when running with Saxon on the command line, I'm getting the warning:

```
Warning: SXXP0005: The source document is in namespace http://xml.house.gov/schemas/uslm/1.0, but all the template rules match elements in no namespace
```

and the output is plain text instead of XML tags.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't rely so heavily on references to external web sites. Some of us distrust links especially to ZIP files, and even if we trust them, it adds to the effort of answering the question. Also the links often disappear in time, making the SO archives less useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using XSLT 2.0 you can add the `xpath-default-namespace` attribute on `xsl:stylesheet`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#standard-attributes for more details.

For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xpath-default-namespace="http://xml.house.gov/schemas/uslm/1.0">
```

You also have the option of using `*` as the prefix for each element in your paths. That could end up being a lot of work though if your stylesheet grows.

Example:

```
ancestor::*:title/*:num
```

Full example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://xml.house.gov/schemas/uslm/1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:result-document href="{ancestor::title/num/@value}-{ancestor::chapter/num/@value}-{num/@value}.xml">
            <structure>
                <unit label="title" identifier="{ancestor::title/num/@value}" 
                    order_by="{ancestor::title/num/@value}" level="1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::title/num,' ',ancestor::title/heading)"/>
                </unit>
            </structure>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Adding the xpath-default-namespace gets it to run without a warning, but it doesn't create a file for each section and is still only outputting text.  Here is what it is producing: 
    Title 1
    USCTitle
    1
    Online@113-31
    OLRC
    2013-07-26T05:14:38
    USCConverter 1.0

Comment: I haven't looked at the data, but are you sure that `section` is a child of `title`? That's what your XSLT is saying.

Comment: Just looked at the data. `section` is a descendant of `title`. Try changing the `select` in the `xsl:for-each` to `chapter/section`.

Comment: @Chris - I added a full example. Also, notice how I didn't use `xsl:element`, `xsl:attribute`, or `xsl:for-each`. The `{}` in the attributes are attribute value templates (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates). Very handy.

Comment: After making that change and using {$href} instead of just $href in the result-document href attribute it worked like a charm!  Thanks for the help.